# How to increase the size of a plot point in Rickshaw js?

Tags: d3.js, rickshaw

I'm using Rickshaw graphs and I have a line graph working just fine. However, I would like to make the plot points visible by increasing their size. Is there a way to do this?

Here is my code:

```
 var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph({
                        element: document.querySelector("#chart"),
                        width: window.innerWidth - 180,
                        height: 300,
                        renderer: 'line',
                        interpolation: 'linear',
                        min: 0,
                        max: 100,
                        series: graphLines
                    });
```

I tried using `graph.renderer.dotSize = 16;`, but it doesn't seem to work on line graphs, only scatter plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I've done in the past is use the 'multi' option and create one line graph with a scatter plot on top of it to simulate the lines